# Changing a static string in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am working on a coding project and I keep running into this issue where I try and make a static text within Android Studio the current date and when ever I reference the Date() class, the app will crash when you try and debug it. It even crashes when there are no errors.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Date date = new Date();

    int currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    int currentDay = date.getDay();
    int currentYear = date.getYear();

    String str = getResources().getString(R.string.date_text);

    private TextView textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_text);
    //private EditText date = Date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        str = currentMonth + " " + currentDay + currentYear;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that there is a string named date_text in the `strings.xml` file.

Here's the logcat image:

[image]

Comment: For a crash it's important to give details about which version of Android Studio, which OS, what step you were on when the crash happened, etc.

Comment: what's the error, please post logcat

Comment: Here is a link to the Logcat http://i.imgur.com/Gte1h3q.png

Answer (score 0):

It's simple because you can't call the `getResources()` outside the method. So, the following code is incorrect:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    // this is incorrect, because context for getResources() not yet initialized.
    String str = getResources().getString(R.string.date_text);

    ...

    // this incorrect, because you didn't have the context yet for finding the view.
    private TextView textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_text);


}
```

You need something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    String str;

    private TextView textOut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initializing the variables
        str = getResources().getString(R.string.date_text);

        // bind the view after setContentView method and before used.
        textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_text);

        str = currentMonth + " " + currentDay + currentYear;
    }

    ...
}
```